# How to get a particular row in listview to perform its own operation?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I need some help here. I have used [this](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) site example on creating a listview. What I want to achieve is when the user clicks a particular row, the row clicked will perform its respective action. (Eg. When clicked row 1 will show a toast. When clicked row 2 will direct the user to another new view, etc.)

I have set a OnItemClickListener to the listview but am lost on how to do it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!
Below is my code:

```
    .......
    final ListView list = new ListView(this);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Adapter<?> arg0, View v, int i, long l){

    // At implementation

     }
    });
    .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track, everything should be clearer with onItemClick's parameter names :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked row " + position,
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So you actually get the position of the item clicked, and can have a different action for each item.

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciate the answer. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of the selected item:

```
int selected_item = myListView.getPositionForView(view);
```

or to get the string:

```
String chosen_item = (myListView.getItemAtPosition(selected_item).toString());
```

If your class is extending ListActivity replace "myListView" with "this".